# Google oAuth 2.0 with Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-oauth

I spent days trying to figure out how to have my app Authenticate against Ggoogle, using Xamarin.Android App.

I Tried OAuth2Authenticator (From Xamarin.Auth). I get Error's such as "Disallowed Url"

```
        var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(clientId: "aaaa-aaaaa.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),
        redirectUrl: new Uri("https://my-domain-test.com/api-v1/User/Welcome"),
        getUsernameAsync: null);
        auth.AllowCancel = allowCancel;

        auth.Completed += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!e.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Fail to authenticate!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                return;
            }
            string access_token;
            e.Account.Properties.TryGetValue("access_token", out access_token);
            //step:3 Google API Request to get Profile Information
            if (await fnGetProfileInfoFromGoogle(access_token))
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Authentcated successfully", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        };
        var intent = auth.GetUI(this);
        StartActivity(intent);
```

Then i also tried Google's oAuth Library

```
        UserCredential credential;
 
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets() { ClientId= "aaaa-aaaa.apps.googleusercontent.com", ClientSecret= "xxx-xxxx-tlD" },
                new[] {"email"},
                "user", CancellationToken.None);
```

it Simple fails on GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync, Instance cant be created.

Did anyone tried to integrate Google oAuth Authentication into their Android Project Successfully? I am running out of ideas.

Comment: GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync does not support xamarin auth. You wil need to code it yourself. Yes i have done it a few years ago for a client so it is doable.

Comment: So if I were to host the Google Auth on a Seperate Web Page, and then simply open Android open upon Successful Login, would that be a acceptable solution?

Comment: Cant anwser that question sounds like a hack to me. Why not just code the authorization within Xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

The `Xamarin.Auth` library has not been updated for a long time.

For the authentication in Xamarin.Forms, try to use the `Xamarin.Essentials` library.

```
var authResult = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(
    new Uri("https://example.com/mobileauth/"),
    new Uri("myapp://"));

var accessToken = authResult?.AccessToken;
```

For more details, refer to the MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=android

Comment: unfortunately it does not work with Google Authentication.

Comment: The Web Authenticator could add user authentication to sign in existing Google  accounts. You could check the link. https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/blob/fe78dad8e2b0d78b7ba3ee5460862e1dbb2ed994/Samples/Sample.Server.WebAuthenticator/Startup.cs#L44